# Insufficient Privileges - JS Button on Child

Tags: javascript, button-overrides, childrecords

Parent= Case
Child = MyCustom__c

I have "New Cust" JS button on MyCustom__c related list - 
-> Now I go to my "Case" record (in Console)
-> Go to related List "MyCustom" -> Click on"New Custom" Button

**Throws following Errors**

> ***Insufficient Privileges**
>
> *You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the
>   owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For
>   more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.*
>
> *Click here to return to the previous page.*

What am I doing wrong here ? Any suggestions -

************ ** "New Custom" JS button code ************

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var url = window.location.pathname; 
url = url.substring(1, url.length); 
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Description, AccountId, Account.Name from Case where id=\'"+url+'\''); 
var Desc = result.getArray("records")[0].Description ; 
var nullbool = (result.getArray("records")[0].AccountId != null ? "true" : "false"); 
if(nullbool == "true") 
{ 
var AccName = result.getArray("records")[0].Account.Name; 
window.location.href='/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I400000006gIa&retURL='+url+'&save_new_url=%2Fa4I%2Fe%3FCF00N40000002qgB2%3D06862219%26CF00N40000002qgB2_lkid%3D'+url+'%26retURL%3D%252'+url+'&00N40000002qgB8='+Desc+'&00Ne000000192L8='+AccName;
} 
else 
{ 
window.location.href='/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I400000006gIa&retURL='+url+'&save_new_url=%2Fa4I%2Fe%3FCF00N40000002qgB2%3D06862219%26CF00N40000002qgB2_lkid%3D'+url+'%26retURL%3D%252'+url+'&00N40000002qgB8='+Desc; 
}
```

I found one know issue here ---- but didn't understood much from there -

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SxweAAC

Answer (score 1):

Service Cloud console is different than regular VF Pages. As the case is opened in a SubTab of the page, accessing Page URL won't give you the case ID.

Replace your URL with following code:

```
String caseId = sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabObjectId();

var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Description, AccountId, Account.Name from Case where id=\'"+caseId+"\'");
```

More details :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getenclosingprimarytabobjectid.htm

Comment: See updated code in Question - Still I am getting "Unexpected Identifier" error

Comment: One more doubt - Will this work for JavaScript Button

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't add a comment on the above answer due to having a new account, so here's a correction:

The method getEnclosingPrimaryTabObjectId is asynchronous and the result can be read in the callback. It doesn't return a value you can assign to a variable. Your code should look more like this

```
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabObjectId(myCallback);

var myCallback = function myCallback(result) { 
    var caseId = result.id;
    alert ('Case ID: ' + caseId);
    var caseResult = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Description, AccountId, Account.Name from Case where id=\'"+caseId+"\'");
    var Desc = caseResult.getArray("records")[0].Description ;
}
```

See docs here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getenclosingprimarytabobjectid.htm